# Multistep form with active steps and lines

Tags: html, css

I am working on a multi-stepped form. I am unsure how to create the line underneath the orbs, but also how to do the steps/active/passed aspects to change the keyline. I need something close to this design.

here is my latest jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/39sg7f3n/20/

[image]

my current code

html

```
<ul className="form-steps">
  <li className={page === 1 ? 'active' : ''}><span><Icon type="rocket" /></span>Step 1</li>
  <li className={page === 2 ? 'active' : ''}><span><Icon type="rocket" /></span>Step 2</li>
  <li className={page === 3 ? 'active' : ''}><span><Icon type="rocket" /></span>Step 3</li>
  <li className={page === 4 ? 'active' : ''}><span><Icon type="rocket" /></span>Step 4</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.form-steps{
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;

    li{
        float:left;
        margin-right: 10px;

        span{
            background: red;
            border-radius: 100%;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            display: block;
            font-size: 25px;
            line-height: 50px;
        }
    }
}
```

so refactoring this may currently look like

```css
    .form-steps{
     overflow:hidden;
     text-align: center;
    }
   .form-steps li{
     float:left;
     margin-right: 10px;
   }
   .form-steps li span{
     background: red;
     border-radius: 100%;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     display: block;
     font-size: 25px;
     line-height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="form-steps">
  <li class="active"><span><Icon type="rocket" /></span>Step 1</li>
  <li class="active"><span><Icon type="rocket" /></span>Step 2</li>
  <li><span><Icon type="rocket" /></span>Step 3</li>
  <li><span><Icon type="rocket" /></span>Step 4</li>
</ul>
```

I have an old bit of code to hand - similar but different design.

```css
ul{list-style:none;}
 ul li{float:left;}
 ul li.active span{color:orange;}
 ul li.inactive span{color:gray;}
 ul li span{display: block;position: relative;text-align: center;padding: 25px;}
 ul li span:first-child:after{content: '';position: absolute;width: 10px;height: 10px;border-radius: 50%;bottom: -8px;left: calc(50% - 5px);z-index:1;}
 ul li.active span:first-child:after{border: 3px solid orange;background-color: white;}
 ul li.inactive span:first-child:after{border: 3px solid gray;background-color: white;}
 ul li:first-child span:last-child:after{content: '';border-top: 1px solid gray;width: 50%;position: absolute;left: 50%;top: 0;}
 ul li:last-child span:last-child:before{content: '';border-top: 1px solid gray;width: 50%;position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;}
 ul li:not(:last-child) span:last-child:after{content: '';border-top: 1px solid gray;width: 50%;position: absolute;left: 50%;top: 0;}
 ul li:not(:first-child) span:last-child:before{content: '';border-top: 1px solid gray;width: 50%;position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="active"><span>Call</span><span>Completed</span></li>
 <li class="inactive"><span>Proposal</span><span>Waiting</span></li>
 <li class="inactive"><span>Hire</span><span></span></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: and old jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/39sg7f3n/9/

Comment: latest jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/39sg7f3n/12/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/39sg7f3n/13/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/39sg7f3n/20/

Comment: actually - I dropped this to use the steps - in antd - so it came with some animation features - and well - it was the same kind of idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below snippet.

```css
.wizard-progress {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wizard-progress li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.wizard-progress .step-name {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 32px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard-progress .step-num {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid darkgray;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.wizard-progress .step-num:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: darkgray;
  height: 1px;
  width: 130%;
  /* 130px; */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45px;
}

.wizard-progress li:last-of-type .step-num:after {
  display: none;
}
.step-done .step-num::after{
 background-color:#000;
}

.wizard-progress .step-done .step-num,
.wizard-progress .step-active .step-num {
  border-color: #000;
  background-color: #000;
}

.wizard-progress .step-active .step-name {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* wizard with 5 steps */

.wizard-5-steps {
  width: 750px;
}

.wizard-5-steps li {
  margin-right: 6.9%;
  /* 6.6687%; 50px */
  width: 13%;
}

.wizard-5-steps .step-num:after {
  left: 62%;
}


/* wizard with 6 steps */

.wizard-6-steps {
  width: 750px;
}

.wizard-6-steps li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5.5%;
  /* 6.6687%; 50px */
  width: 11%;
}

.wizard-6-steps .step-num:after {
  left: 64%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container center-block">
  <ol class="wizard-progress wizard-5-steps clearfix center-block">
    <li class="step-done">
      <span class="step-num">1</span>
      <span class="step-name">program</span>
    </li>
    <li class="step-done">
      <span class="step-num">2</span>
      <span class="step-name">appointment</span>
    </li>
    <li class="step-active">
      <span class="step-num">3</span>
      <span class="step-name">time</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="step-num">4</span>
      <span class="step-name">contact</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="step-num">5</span>
      <span class="step-name">review</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Check the updated [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/39sg7f3n/14/)

Comment: Yours looks a little squashed.

Comment: check the updated one. I recommend this only for wizard changes. you can update step number with icons.

Comment: @TheOldCounty so what do you need on this?

Comment: -your version feels too complex in the css and squashed.

Comment: I mean what change you are expecting on your fiddler?

Comment: -- well the link line is leaving gaps

Answer (score 0):

Multi Step Form using JavaScript and jQuery.

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
      next_fs.css({
        'left': left,
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'left': left
      });
      previous_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
  return false;
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/
  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2c3e50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27ae60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27ae60;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}


/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}


/*marking active/completed steps green*/


/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```